# Table with multiple counts in one row

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a solution to become a nice table, that looks like this:

```
ID   | A      | B      | C
-------------------------------
1    | 15     | 4      | 3
2    | 3      | 7      | 1
```

The source is like this:

```
ID  | Type
--------------
1   | A
2   | A
1   | C
1   | C
2   | C
1   | B
2   | A
1   | B
```

Now I've to count all the A-Type and all the B-Type per ID.

Is there an easy way?

Thanks

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code if you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array). Note also that in relational databases, tables are required to have PRIMARY KEYs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks minimal effort. Improve your question by updating it with the code that you've tried and where you're having difficulties.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I'd no idea on how to start :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of data transformation is known as a pivot. MySQL doesn't have a pivot function but you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select id,
  count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) A,
  count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) B,
  count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end) C
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f7be5/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is named sometable...

```
select ID, 
sum(if(Type="A",1,0)) as A,
sum(if(Type="B",1,0)) as B,
sum(if(Type="C",1,0)) as C
from someTable
group by ID
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: And why did this get downvoted?

Comment: I have no clue why this was downvoted but we both got one. This syntax is correct and it is MySQL specific.